# Dynamically block IP addresses that have reached a honeypot

Tags: java, spring-boot, honeypot

Happy new 2020.

I have a question regarding the functionality of blocking IP addresses that have reached a honeypot system.

I have a real system **A** and a honeypot **B**.
The honeypot (**B**) is a completely different application from **A**.

Both systems (**A** and **B**) are Spring Boot applications.

However, what I want to achieve is when, let's say, a hacker reaches the honeypot **B**, its IP address to get dynamically blacklisted in the real application **A** but also the hacker should be able to keep operating with the honeypot **B**.

*Update: After the IP address is blocked for the real system, the hacker should still be able to interact with the honeypot. 
Describing the following scenario: 
A hacker opens the real system and by hidden hints inside the HTML source code of the application, they navigate to the honeypot system. 
The honeypot system itself contains low hanging fruits that seem open to attacks - such as fields where you can execute SQL injections.

When the hacker makes attempts to perform SQL injections - the honeypot is collecting all the information - what the intruder is doing. 
And once the intruder hits the honeypot - their IP address gets blocked for the real application but remains active for the honeypot. 
So the hacker doesn't know that they were blocked for the real application and they keep performing SQL injections to the honeypot.*

The first solution that came up to my mind is to make an http call from the honeypot to the real system - providing the IP address of the intruder and blacklisting it with internal mechanism from the real system itself. /however, I am not sure if it is the best approach here/

*Update: The internal mechanism of the real system is nothing else but an internal cache holding IP addresses that should not interact with the real system itself. When there is an incoming request the IP address of the client is checked and those requests coming from a blacklisted IPs are not served.*

Another solution is to use a reverse proxy but I was not able to find a suitable way of doing it.

I would appreciate your help in finding an easy solution or providing me an idea for a different approach in this situation.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two questions, you need to clarify what you mean by `the hacker should be able to keep operation with the honeypot B.` how would application B be affected by it being blacklisted from using a other application? Second `blacklisting it with internal mechanism from the real system itself.` i have no idea what you mean by this?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with more details.

Comment: you are still very unclear and you are using bad terminology. You say `they navigate to the real system `what are we talking, i new host, a new ip, a new client? new webpage served from a new client?

Comment: I think you are being very naive, its very easy to track where requests are going unless you hide it all behind a reverse proxy that reroutes requests in the background.